# RelayCommand Won't Execute On Button Click

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, relaycommand

I've been stuck on this problem for a few hours. I am attempting to implement an MVVM-style Word Add-In in WPF. I am not using an MVVM toolkit. I have a WPF user control that is docked within a WinForm. While I am able to see the WPF user control within the win form and interact with it, my generic `RelayCommand<T>` that is bound to a WPF button won't execute when I click the button. The `RelayCommand` lives in ViewModel.cs and the `DataContext` for the view is set through the code-behind. I'm sure I'm doing something silly, but can't figure out what it is and therefore not sure why `RelayCommand` property's `get{}` won't get executed. Please see the code below. Thanks in advance for the help!

**RelayCommand.cs** (code snippet excludes namespace and includes statements)

```
/// <summary>
/// RelayCommand
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Generic Parameter</typeparam>
public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand where T : class
{
    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// RelayCommand constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="exec">Delegate that encapsulates a method that takes in a single parameter and returns void</param>
    /// <param name="canExec">Delegate that encapsulates a method that defines a set of criteria and returns a true if criteria is met; else false</param>
    public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute, Predicate<T> canExecute = null)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute is null");

        _canExecute = canExecute;
        _execute    = execute;
    }

    #endregion
    #region Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Execute method
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="param">Parameter</param>
    public void Execute(object param)
    {
        T obj = param as T;

        if(obj != null)
        {
            _execute(obj);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// CanExec is a method that shows whether or not execution can happen
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="param">Parameter</param>
    /// <returns>true if can execute; else false</returns>
    public bool CanExecute(object param)
    {
        if (_canExecute == null)
            return true;

        T obj = param as T;
        return obj == null || _canExecute(obj);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// CanExec event changed
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Fields

    private readonly Predicate<T> _canExecute;
    private readonly Action<T> _execute;

    #endregion
}
```

**SubmissionUserControl.xaml** (only the pertinent snippet. excludes some code)

```
<Button Grid.Column="2" x:Name="SubmitButton" Command="{Binding Path=SubmitCommentCommand}"
                        Content="Submit" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5"/>
```

**SubmissionUserControl.xaml.cs** (contains snippet where I reference the ViewModel)

```
ViewModel viewModel;
public SubmissionUserControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    viewModel = new ViewModel();
    DataContext = viewModel;
}
```

**ViewModel.cs** (excludes some code. only shows the pertinent RelayCommand)

```
/// <summary>
/// SubmitCommentCommand responsible for interacting with UI to submit a comment.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Returns a RelayCommand that executes a method to Save comments from the comment box</returns>
public ICommand SubmitCommentCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _submitCommentCommand ?? (_submitCommentCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(param => this.SaveComment()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing is wrong in your code.. check the Datacontext is applied correctly.. add another text property and bound it to a textblock and check that displays?

Comment: use Snoop (http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to check your datacontext on runtime

Comment: it seems to me that your not sending a command parameter , and in your RelayCommand implementation you for some reason only call execute if the parameter isn't null.

Comment: Why are you using ICommand instead of RelayCommand in your ViewModel.cs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give you a more detailed start into MVVM and RelayCommands:

You do not have to declare your ViewModel in Xaml, this is mostly done programmatically on application root level, maybe with some DI.

When sticking to this [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) your RelayCommand should look like this:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    #region Fields

    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    #endregion // Fields

    #region Constructors

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }
    #endregion // Constructors

    #region ICommand Members

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    #endregion // ICommand Members
}
```

Additionally you can define a generic RelayCommand to handle Commandparameters like this:

```
public class GenericRelayCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<T> _execute;
    public Predicate<T> CanExecuteFunc { get; private set; }

    public GenericRelayCommand(Action<T> execute) : this(execute, p => true)
    {}

    public GenericRelayCommand(Action<T> execute, Predicate<T> canExecuteFunc)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        CanExecuteFunc = canExecuteFunc;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        var canExecute = CanExecuteFunc((T)parameter);
        return canExecute;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute((T)parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }
    }
}
```

In your ViewModel the RelayCommands should be definied like this (I implemented INotifyPropertyChanged as well for further WPF Xaml Property handling example):

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _comment;
    public string Comment
    {
        get { return _comment; }
        set { _comment = value; OnPropertyChanged("Comment"); }
    }

    public GenericRelayCommand<string> SubmitComment1Command { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand SubmitComment2Command { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Comment = "Hello World!";
        SubmitComment1Command = new GenericRelayCommand<string>(OnSubmitComment1);
        SubmitComment2Command = new RelayCommand(OnSubmitComment2);
    }

    private void OnSubmitComment1(string obj)
    {
        //Save Comment Mock with CommandParameter
        MessageBox.Show(obj);    
    }

    private void OnSubmitComment2(object obj)
    {
        //Save Comment Mock with Property
        MessageBox.Show(Comment);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

I put your Button Example into a fresh WPF Application like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="525"
        Height="350">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0"
                    Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox Name="textBox"
                     Width="200"
                     Text="{Binding Comment,
                                    Mode=TwoWay,
                                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            <Button x:Name="SubmitButton1"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Margin="5"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    Command="{Binding Path=SubmitComment1Command}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=textBox,
                                               Path=Text}"
                    Content="Submit1" />
        </StackPanel>


        <Button x:Name="SubmitButton2"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Margin="5"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                Command="{Binding Path=SubmitComment2Command}"
                Content="Submit2" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And set the DataContext like this for simplicity reasons (As stated before, this is normally done through some kind of DI at root level):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

Then everything should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I basically started over added tested bit-by-bit.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by telling the Model about data context in XAML instead of .cs file.

**First:** Tell Model the `namespace` in which you placed your view model, mine was like below:

```
xmlns:Local="clr-namespace:MKPL.Views.A01.S020"
```

**Second:** Add your ViewModel in XAML `Resources` like:

```
<UserControl.Resources>  
        <Local:ViewModel x:Key="dvm"/>   
</UserControl.Resources>
```

**Third:** Add `DataContext` to the parent container,in my case that is `Grid`.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource dvm}}">
```

**Fourth:** In your button code add the data context like:

```
<Button Grid.Column="2" x:Name="SubmitButton" Command="{Binding Path=SubmitCommentCommand, Source={StaticResource dvm}}"
                        Content="Submit" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5"/>
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks, to all who responded. This particular solution worked for me.

Comment: @user3317801 if this soln work for you then kindly mark it as a answer to help others noticing it.

Comment: I think I spoke too soon. I tried the solution earlier in the afternoon and thought it was successful because upon launch of the  add-in, the SubmitCommentCommand was called, but tonight when I try to re-launch the app I notice that the command executes at no other time except at launch. Guess it always did so and I never noticed. Anyway, not sure what's going on here. I'm going to try downloading snoop as another person who commented on this question suggests and see what happens.

Comment: @user3317801 well you should give GalaSoft a try, it is for MVVM pattern and i tested my solution with it.

Comment: Just to let you know, I think your solution could work, but I noticed one warning the XAML editor in Visual Studio gave me. This could be the source of my problem: Basically when I name the view model in the UserControl.Resources tag, namely <local:ViewModel x:key="vm"/>, the warning says "The ViewModel does not exist in the namespace clr-...". Think there is anyway to avoid this? I know the ViewModel exists and compiles. Not sure why XAML isn't recognizing it. I declare make the local declaration by saying up top xmlns:Local="clr-namespace:AppName" since its in the top level of the directory.

Comment: @user3317801 did you make your view model public ??
make it public and compile it again

Comment: Yes, view model was already public and compiled again. I notice in your solution, you don't set the data context and snoop says the data context is null. I removed the code-behind setting of datacontext because i thought that the source tag in the binding of the button referring to the view model key was enough. Am I wrong to have removed this? Should I have set this through the xaml tag? I've seen others set Datacontext by saying <UserControl.DataContext></UserControl.DataContext> and I've seen others set the DataContext directly within other controls such as <Grid DataContext="vm">

Comment: @user3317801 :
i guess u have to do this <br>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
          Height="470"
          DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource dvm}}"
</Grid>

Comment: @user3317801 if this works for you, let me know i will update the answer accordingly. One more thing i assign the DataSource to my Grid because that Grid contains all the other controls so make sure to assign DataContext to the parent one.